# Do noumena exist only if we are modal nihilists?

Tags: kant, noumenon

At face value, it's difficult to translate the two discussions/terms, but is the "nothingness" of noumenon an **empty world**? Do [noumenon](https://epochemagazine.org/04/revisiting-the-noumenon/) exist only with modal nihilism,

> the view that there is a possible world which contains no concrete
> objects

(from a [discussion](https://www-users.york.ac.uk/%7Etwcs1/Blogger/philosophy.html) about question begging from modal nihilists)?

I think a noumenon, which it is claimed is "nothingness", cannot be a **local absence**, part of a world. If only because I may be able to talk about the noumenon, but I may be unable to divide it from other things, in my [imagination](https://philpapers.org/rec/MARCKM), in any sense (Kant calls it "chaos" I think).

Maybe I've misunderstood how modal semantics or mereology (maybe e.g. a post modern like failure or limit of language does not need to be about something that is either a part of a world or a world) about noumenon would work.

Anything seems naively plausible, but I lean toward my conclusion, completely naively, that what we can't experience is a world with "nothing at all".

Comment: My (limited) understanding is that Kant's view is that the actual world is both thing-in-itself (noumenon) and also objective reality conditioned by transcendental conceptual structures? In the actual world, the noumenon is a pre-objective reality, but that very same reality when seen through transcendental structures does have objects (e.g., stars, planets, plants, tables, etc).  In the other direction, a "world" in the modal logic sense is already an object in the Kantian sense since it is an element of a set of possible worlds.  So a possible world with an empty domain can't be a noumenon.

Comment: I should add that I have not had a chance to read the article you linked to. The author might have a non-standard reading or Kant or a non-Kantian notion of noumenon.

Comment: This question requires some clarification. The claim being made in the quoted paragraph is that a noumenon is a concept under which no object falls, just like a contradiction such as "a thing not equal to itself" is a concept under which no object falls. How do you get from this to an empty world? A thing not equal to itself does not exist in an empty world. Why would a noumenon? As to the concept of a noumenon, clearly the concept exists in our world, which is not empty.

Comment: again @DavidGudeman I don't think you've shown that an empty world is an "object" in Kant's sense

Comment: it is not a leap of faith to think that a nothingness is an empty world, and I am asking whether or not it is. I think it might be, by suggesting that it cannot be a part

Comment: @not_again_back, I have not shown anything. I have asked you to clarify your point because the question does not seem to follow in any way from the setup.

Comment: @DavidGudeman would you be happier if I deleted the "setup" and let people guess what I mean by noumenon?

Comment: No. I am asking that you explain where the question comes from. Why would you think that noumenon can only exist if there is a possible world in which nothing exists? Now that you deleted that paragraph the question is even more puzzling. No one is going to know what you mean by a noumenon being "nothingness". The quote at least illuminated that odd turn of phrase.

Comment: @DavidGudeman I am asking whether it is the sort of nothingness that an empty world is. I do not need any further detail for the question to make sense, however puzzling the comment section finds it

Comment: I am sorry that you find my efforts to understand your thought processes so trying.

Comment: It's fine @DavidGudeman you are clearly struggling to communicate also

Comment: @AviC do you mean that the actual world cannot include an empty world in the way that this world includes noumena?

Comment: I think you're just trying to be unhelpful in order to encourage others to do likewise. While this is highly annoying, I doubt it is original to you ha @DavidGudeman

Comment: I was trying to be helpful. How can you know where your writing is unclear if no one tells you? On the other hand, who is going to tell you if you react defensively to well-intentioned criticism? I believe intellectual exploration should be a cooperative enterprise, but it requires cooperation on both ends.

Comment: So what's unclear @DavidGudeman if you cannot say, don't be surprised if I am defensive

Comment: Maybe you can pick out a phrase you don't understand or inference I make you cannot follow. I don't know what else could be puzzling you @DavidGudeman unless you didn't read the question title so are lost what question I'm aksing

Comment: Really, you don't need to know why I said exactly everything I said in the order I said it in order to understand a question.

Comment: forget it. this is not a helpful site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your question is based on an incomplete understanding of what noumena are, at least in Kant.

Noumena are not *separate entities*, at least not as they are originally introduced in the CPR.

One could say that they are the other side of any thing we can empirically verify as existing in our world, like the other side of a coin that you can't flip and hence will never see the backside of. If we see the whole coin, we do not suddenly see two different objects.

That would still be a misleading picture though: introduced as *purely negative idea*, they are the (possible) object of perception like it is without being modified by any *mode of perception*. For example, Kant says we perceive objects in relations of time and space to ourselves and one another. This is, he argues, *our mode of perception*. Therefore, we have to assume that the objects of perception, if not perceived through the 'glasses' of time and space, may turn out to - in themselves - lack any spacey or timey relations or properties.

That, for once, means they are *definitely* outside of our world and, in a sense, in 'nothingness' since 'the world' is 'the sum of all possible experience' in Kant. And we cannot experience noumena. On the other hand, this would either be an attempt of *positively* determining them given we use any substantial concept of nothingness, or it would literally be meaningless to say. For Kant, both options are the same since noumena cannot possibly be determined positively by us mere humans due to how our understanding works. It would be a meaningless string of words either way.

Does all this mean Kant has to commit to modal nihilism? Well, in a trivial sense yes, since it is a *logical possibility* that the noumenal world does not contain any concrete objects. On the other hand, taking his epistemological position seriously, we should certainly *not commit* to modal nihilism but rather insist that *it is moot to talk about such things since we simply cannot possibly know*.

Comment: OK. Are empty worlds "separate entities"?

Comment: @unhelpful_people_rules The noumenal world certainly is not empty, nor does "no concrete objects" mean empty. It could be full of information we just cannot organise into concrete objects.

Comment: I just quoted someone that said than an world that has "no concrete object" is a world that is "empty". I am genuinely confused!

Comment: @unhelpful_people_rules Well yeah, basically Kant's view is that while *we* have to perceive in particular objects in spatiotemporal relations that doesn't mean that every being has to, nor that this is how things are, taken our mode of perception away. Thus, the noumenal world could well be "empty for beings like us" without being an empty set or the like. We may not see any *thing* there...

Comment: OK I get it... you cannot infer that Kant's noumenon is an "empty world" because doing so would be knowledge for us. Right? That's a bit of a trip thinking about 'critical philosophy' and its uniqueness.

Comment: @unhelpful_people_rules Right. It would be saying something about something we cannot know anything about, so mere pretension.

Comment: @unhelpful_people_rules And yes, Kant's whole critical philosophy is about sowing out all these pretentious metaphysics that make assertions about how things are or could be beyond the boundaries of what we actually can know.

Comment: yeah, radical. thanks for the elaboration.

Answer (score 0):

Inasmuch as at least some classes of noumena could be objects of intellectual intuition, then inasmuch as intuition compasses its objects *in particular* and so *in concreto*, a world containing noumena would not be a world containing only general facts and abstract objects (indeed, an abstract object is not supposed to exist *in* a concrete world except in the slight sense of concrete objects instantiating abstract properties; although see also [discussion of "contingently abstract" things](https://www.jstor.org/stable/4320719)).

However, Kant *does* bring up noumena in his fourfold table of "forms of nothingness," so there is a metaphysical nihilism entangled in his terminology on this score, but it is not a nihilism of [empty worlds](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/nothingness/#TheMosOneEmpWor) insofar as Kant did not make his modal metaphysics depend on such a strong notion as a full array of possible (and impossible) worlds. Noumenal emptiness is not absolute emptiness; it is not the void of contradiction, but a different void.

One might think of it in terms of analogies between the fourfold nothingness of the first Critique, and Platonic Forms of Zero, Imperfection/Imperfect Participation, Nonexistence, Destruction, etc. The differences between such Forms, and the logical problems they face (at least in Plato's theories), might be comparable to the identities of/issues with the Critique-voids. Noumena need not be inexistent; neither destructive or imperfect self-participants; they are closer to an "empty set," here, perhaps, then. But so again, not an absence of an object so much as an objectual absence. (This raises the question of whether an otherwise empty world could be reasonably construed as having at least one object to its name regardless, namely its own emptiness as an object. Monism about the number of concrete objects in a world often ends up styling a given world as the one such object "of" each such world, with e.g. "The fox is in the garden," as something like, "The world is arranged (fox-in-a-garden)wise here," so an empty world might be such as, "The (one object that is the) empty world is arranged nothingness-wise throughout.")

Comment: oh right well that's answered the question so I accepted it. Thought I had deleted the question

Comment: What do you mean by "objectual absence"? Without knowing, I do not know the relevance of suggesting that an empty world is an empty set. You seem to covertly start with the assumption that noumena exist, which may be where we disagree

Comment: @unhelpful_people_rules, an objectual absence is when we treat an absence, like a hole, as a presence of its own. Now I don't need to say that any noumena "really" exist, for my reasoning to flow well enough; maybe not even that they are *knowably* possibly existent. Just that, per Kant's table of nothingness, their place on that table is akin to some other possible table of nothingness with empty sets under one of four (or however many) headings. (OTOH, empty space/time on Kant's table might be more akin to empty sets... But then noumena are less like empty worlds, too.)

Comment: Empty worlds, according to the subtraction argument, it seems, are formed when concrete objects do not exist in them http://media.philosophy.ox.ac.uk/assets/pdf_file/0006/27447/The_subtraction_arguments_compared_and_defended.pdf . So it is not sufficient to show that noumena are concrete. And I do not see how showing they are akin to an empty set shows they are not an empty world. I might agree that empty worlds are not "present" to us though

Comment: @unhelpful_people_rules, if we're going off Kant's definitions, this is just how it is. However, we can of course *reformulate* the levels of the noumenon-concept, so that we might characterize empty concrete worlds as noumena "after a fashion." However, how much understanding (of nothingness or anything else) is gained by such redefining of terms?

Comment: Can you quote from Kant to explicitly show that, for Kant, a concrete noumenon, or empty set, cannot be an empty world? In general, we might be able to translate any philosophy into a contemporary discussion without loss of meaning. Have you shown that noumenon do not make for a world, or that it would have something existing within in?

Comment: Perhaps I missed an implied point (one I missed due to not knowing the first critique) against my suggestion that noumenon is never a part and so must be a world (or demonstrated that things might exist inside it). In which case, my apologies

Comment: Is an "empty world" just a world with "nothing inside it"? It definitely makes sense to me to suggest that if something is not a part of a world and is nothing then it is a world with nothing inside it. Unless we say it is outside all worlds (possible or otherwise). Is it a world that is nothing?

Comment: @unhelpful_people_rules, I think Kant does say that we can imagine empty space/time, and spaces/times are his closest things to sets (as mathematically foundational). But so they also form the structure of our world, so empty worlds would be empty spacetimes. "An empty world" might be an example of a kind of noumenon (an object of pure thought), though; but we can "believe in" noumena in general without believing in empty worlds. So I guess my answer to the OP question is, "Noumena 'might' exist even if no world is empty."

Comment: "without believing in empty worlds" right I think I get what you mean

Comment: I would agree that we can believe empty worlds exist and not noumena. but can we believe noumena exist and believe empty worlds are impossible?